# Random 408 http code with CURL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, random

I have a problem with a CURL request i make in php. The issue is that at random times it returns a timeout. What i noticed is that after i added custom error pages the 404 custom page works but the 408 page when done with curl returns nothing.

Example of 404 page: http://emailingrestauraweb.com/qweqwe

Below is my php code:

```
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $this->SessionID;
$curl_log = fopen("curl.txt", 'w');
//Setup connection
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl,array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $URL,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>$this->UserAgent,
        CURLOPT_POST =>true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($arrParams, null, '&'),
        CURLOPT_COOKIE => $strCookie,
        CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION=>1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE         => 0,           // Logs verbose output to STDERR
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,           // Do not verify certificate
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT=>260,
        CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL => 1,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>1
    ));

    //Send request
    $result_json = curl_exec($curl);
    $error_code =curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
```

I tried everything i have no idea why this happens and it's random too.

## UPDATE 1

I run the scripts on 2 slicehost slices. I make a request from one slice to another to an api. The api is an OEMPRO software for sending emails.
I understand that 408 means timeout but this seems to random and most of the time it's repetitive like a block and i'm wondering if this could be something that that software might use.

This issue happened after my domain where OEMPRO is running expired for like 3 days and then it went back and now i have this problem...

Thanks for all the answers.

Comment: 408 is a timeout... you know this, right?

Comment: Are these error pages also PHP? Any htaccess as well?

Comment: Yes i know 408 is a timeout. The thing is if you define an error page for the timeout then why does it not display. Could this be an error in my curl? That's what i'm wondering to be sincere.

Comment: @HappyTimeGopher the error pages are a single php page that gets the code and shows a message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said your domain was expired for 3 days. There is a high probability that this was a DNS resolve issue. Give it 24-48 hours and let us know if there is any change.

Comment: yes that is true today it seemed that the error doesn't happen that often i will try further and see if 408 occurs if not this seems to be the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A 408 does often not return (contain) a response body. The server just wants to close the connection to you don't want to bother any longer with your slow request.

Sure the standard allows to pass a body, and well somewhat if you read it conservative, it even should return that entity for explanation, but, well, do not depend on it. There ain't any message anyway. Retry the request instead.

Comment: That's definitely not true. I 408 may return a response body, nothing in the spec that does not allow this: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4.9

Comment: I see what you mean and i tought of it but the thing i noticed is that even if i make the request recursively the answer is still 408 for like 20 seconds or more... And it seems like a block from the server. I run these scripts on 2 slices under slicehost and i'm wondering if you guys ran into this before?